# Getting a dark look and feel?

Tags: java, swing

I am bored of the standard look and feel of Swing and need some dark  and black themes which are supposed to look cool.  None of DefaultMetal,Ocean,Motif or Windows which come as a part of the swing satisfy my needs. Is using [nifty-gui](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/) a good idea since I need to have tabbed panes and things like that?  If not are there any other options for me?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [`JTatoo`](http://www.jtattoo.net/) look and feel set, it is open source and could satisfy your needs.

Look at this `NoireLookAndFeel`:

[image: NoireLookAndFeel]

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NoireLookAndFeel.class.getName());
```

Comment: JTatoo has horrible performance problems that will bring your machine to a crawl