# How can i implement dark and light mode in a java swing gui application?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I am fairly new to coding and I am working on a desktop application where I want to implement a dark and light mode. The problem is that I want to switch back and forth between the two, in the main class I have an instantiation of a class that represents my main view of the app if I pass and if I add an action that switches to dark/light mode it only affects the popups because the function is called after the instantiation of the main view it has the same effect if I call the function before the instantiation. I tried all sorts of solutions but I can't figure it out. If anybody has an idea thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```java
import view.MainFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame mainFrame = MainFrame.getInstance();
    }
}
```

```java
import controller.ActionManager;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static MainFrame instance = null;
    private MenuBar RuMenuBar;
    private ToolBar toolBar;
    private ActionManager actionManager;

    private MainFrame(){ }

    private void initialiseActionManager() {
        actionManager = new ActionManager();
    }


    private void initialiseGUI() {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension sc = tk.getScreenSize();
        int height = sc.height;
        int width = sc.width;
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Dokru");
        
        
        RuMenuBar = new MenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(RuMenuBar);
      
        toolBar = new ToolBar();

        add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel treePanel = new JPanel();

       // JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(treePanel); todo scroll
        JPanel workspacePanel = new JPanel();
        JSplitPane splitPane = new 
        JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,treePanel,workspacePanel);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(300);
        getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static MainFrame getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new MainFrame();
            instance.initialiseActionManager();
            instance.initialiseGUI();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: For dark mode you want to apply dark look-and-feel (LAF). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049020/getting-a-dark-look-and-feel)

Comment: Changing the look and feel after the GUI is visible can be tricky. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) which shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Happy to add more content in this section, this looks like a modern question for a very old framework like a swing.

However, there are opportunities to support this change in Java Swing, there are libraries like [FlatLaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/) or [material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing) that give the possibility to implement different style in your app.

I'm the author of [material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing) so I will describe it, In particular, because It implements a concept of Material Theme (Since 2019) like the modern framework such as Flutter or Compose.

In fact, you can implement a custom theme as Jar and include it inside an external library, and an example can be [DarkStackOverflowTheme](https://github.com/material-ui-swing/DarkStackOverflowTheme).

To support the Dark mode and lite mode on your app, you can basically use the UI Manager to switch the Material theme in the MaterialUISwing(dark or lite theme).

Your question is a generic question but  did some demo that include also the switch of the theme in the JMenuBar, you can take a look to [DemoSwingRatio](https://github.com/material-ui-swing/DemoSwingRatio)

Comment: What are "Flutter" and "Compose"? I'm not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the system look and feel, you should get this automatically.

```
try {
    // Set System L&F
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: *"The problem is that I want to switch back and forth between the two"* This does not address the problem.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't see that. That sounds like a trap; The system L&F is the only one you should ever use. Maybe there's a way to intercept or override it's check for dark mode.

Comment: *"The system L&F is the only one you should ever use."* Minus one. That's just nonsense.

Comment: The question doesn’t specify whether switching should happen when the desktop itself is switched to dark mode, or whether only this one application should be individually switchable.  In the absence of that information, this answer can be considered correct;  using the system look-and-feel should pick up system switches to and from dark mode, high contrast mode, etc.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can you explain why it's nonsense? System look and feel (at least Windows and Mac) are the most consistent, most reliable, and are the least tacky/cheap looking. They require zero added dependencies and zero cost.

Comment: Check my answer, I develop one of my library to fix this problem of witch, like flutter or compose

Comment: @Charlie Here are some reasons not to use the System look and feel. **1.** If it's a cross-platform app, you may want it to look the same on all platforms, especially if your UI has non-standard elements. **2.** If marketing wants to incorporate your company logo's color scheme. **3.** There may be a bug in the system L&F, which inhibits the use of a UI feature. 
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69514258) for an example of a bug in the Mac's AquaLookAndFeel.

Comment: 1. That's an antipattern in my book. 2. Marketing should not get to control UX. 3. I'll comment there.